# Why can't I neither delete nor rename the file?

Tags: java, file, writer, reader

While creating a method to my class, I got an unexpected problem. I've tried solutions from other theards, but they just don't work for me. My method should simply find the line specified, copy the file skipping unnecessary line, delete the original file and rename temporary file to the name of original file. It succesfuly creates new file as expected, but then fails to delete previous one as it fails to rename temporary file to original. I can't figure out, why?

```
void lineDelete(String file_name, String line_to_erase){
    try {
        int line_number = 0;
        String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        File temp = new File("temporary.txt");
        File theFile = new File(file_name+".txt");
        String path = theFile.getCanonicalPath();
        File filePath = new File(path);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name + ".txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

        String lineToRemove = line_to_erase;
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)){
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(currentLine + newline));
        }
        writer.close(); 
        reader.close();
        filePath.delete();
        temp.renameTo(theFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: The posted code doesn't even compile. tempFile is not defined. Post the actual code, that really has the problem. Use Files.delete and Files.move: you'll get execptions explaining what the problem is.

Comment: No, I didn't get any exceptions, and sorry about tempFile, forgot about changing that to temp. I edited the original code so the variables would be more clear.

Comment: where is your project located ? location of the workspace ?

Comment: C:/users/user/sublime text/java/,
but this is a project, and it needs to run in any directory that it will be. So after moving it to any directory and compiling it, it should run smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
void lineDelete(String file_name, String line_to_erase){
try {
    int line_number = 0;
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    File temp = new File("temporary.txt");
    File theFile = new File(file_name+".txt");
    String path = theFile.getCanonicalPath();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

    String lineToRemove = line_to_erase;
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)){
            continue;
        }
        writer.write(currentLine + newline));
    }
    writer.close(); 
    reader.close();
    theFile.delete();
    temp.renameTo(file_name + ".txt");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that file file_name.txt already exists before i run the method, and it contains several lines change anything?
And temp.renameTo() is a File type method, and a string such as ".txt" cannnot be used in it.

Comment: No. The thing is, you only call a method to rename a file to another file's name, after you delete the previous one. Since you said your logic is ok, and the temporary file gets the output you wish, the only thing you need to do is what i posted in my answer

Comment: Actually, i wouldn't do it as you are doing. if you are giving a file name that already exists you should use File.open, then check if it exists and if it does, do your logic

Comment: I never used file.open before, could you possibly explain it in brief words?

Comment: @JanekSławiński - There is no such thing as `File.open` or `file.open`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it works as you have coded it, never mind. Anyway, did it fix your problem?*

Comment: @Stephen C , Ye it does, but in python, not java :p my bad

Comment: Nope im still stuck at the same part. I've tried diffrect variations, and I still don't know how to open the file without creating new file.

Comment: Okay, I've done some changes myself and seems like to problem is that it can't delete, nor overwrite the file that is being read. Is it possible that I don't have permission to do that, while changing name of temporary.txt to "whatever.txt" works just fine?

Comment: I dont know in which OS you are running your project, but it is possible it doesn't have permissions to delete files.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest a couple of reasons why the delete and/or rename might fail, but there is a better way to solve your problem than guessing<sup>1</sup>.

If you use `Path` and the `Files.delete(Path)` and `Files.move(Path, Path, CopyOption...)` methods, they will throw exceptions if the operations fail.  The exception name and message should give you clues as to what is *actually* going wrong.

The javadoc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

---

<sup>1 - Here are a couple of guesses: 1) the file has been opened elsewhere, and it is locked as a result. 2) You don't have access to delete the file.</sup>